# What could be wrong with this request in AJAX and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I'm trying to call a PHP page passing parameters with AJAX. I can see that the page is called, but the $_REQUEST doesn't take any parameters. If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

My AJAX is that:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.c_x').change(function(){
            var href = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "utils/inc_iscrizione.php",
                data: 'cod_evento=' + href,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("data:" + data);
                }
            });
        }) 
    });
    
</script>
```

In the PHP Page, I have this.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["cod_evento"]))
{
    $search = $_REQUEST["cod_evento"];
    echo "<script>alert('OK');</script>";
}
else
{
    $search = "";
    echo "<script>alert('FAIL');</script>";
}
```

Always the answer is failure. Thank you!

Comment: Check the network tab. Is Jquery sending it as json?

Comment: No. It is not json.

Comment: Well then what does the request body look like in the tab?

Comment: https://site_address/associati/admin/iscrizionelst.php

Comment: I would also recommend using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` when fetching POST data. Depending on your PHP settings (in php.ini), the `$_REQUEST`-super global can be populated from multiple sources (GET, POST and Cookies) with different priorities and can cause side effects if you're not careful.

Comment: When you make an AJAX request, it generally doesn’t make sense to return more JavaScript wrapped in HTML script tags. Are you seeing `FAIL` literally?

Comment: When using jQuery ajax, it's better to define the data to send like this: `data: {cod_evento: href}`. jQuery will then format it correctly and also urlencode the values properly to prevent issues. Btw, what is the link you posted? Is that the full request body!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- change your data format in ajax request from data:'cod_evento=' + href, to data : {code_evento:href}

2 - change your php echo from echo "alert('OK');" to echo "OK"; and same for else clause

Recommended
1 - change $_REQUEST to $_POST
2 - change alert('data:'+ data) to console.log(data)